# Transposing columns to rows in the same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table :

```
EmployeeId Dept1 Dept2 Dept3
150        10    55    6
```

this is the query to get that result :

```
SELECT  EmployeeId, Dept1, Dept2, Dept3 FROM Employee_History
```

This is my expected output :

```
EmployeeId Dept
150        10
150        55
150        6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a clause in Oracle as UNPIVOT which allows you to transpose the rows dynamically -

```
WITH DATA AS (SELECT 150 EmployeeId, 10 Dept1, 55 Dept2, 6 Dept3 FROM DUAL)
SELECT EmployeeId, DEPT
  FROM (SELECT * FROM DATA
        UNPIVOT (DEPT FOR NAMES IN (Dept1 AS 'Dept1',
                                    Dept2 AS 'Dept2',
                                    Dept3 AS 'Dept3'
                                   )
                )
       );
```

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c4c266cfef5664577b68d87c7e6cfeec)

You still have to pass the list of departments in IN clause of UNPIVOT, So the best possible solution is already provided by Littlefoot.

Answer (score 1):

`UNION` 3 `dept` columns:

```
SQL> select employee_id, dept1 as dept from employee_history
  2  union all
  3  select employee_id, dept2 as dept from employee_history
  4  union all
  5  select employee_id, dept3 as dept from employee_history;

EMPLOYEE_ID       DEPT
----------- ----------
        150         10
        150         55
        150          6

SQL>
```

Comment: is there any way to do it dynamically ?

Comment: There's nothing *dynamic* in what you posted, so - why would solution be *dynamic*? Dynamic in what way?

Comment: @MartinJames, there's a way, but you should have asked about that precisely in your post. You can always edit your question, though. Anyway, you've already accepted an answer which does not provide any dynamic solution, so why bother...