# Transposing columns to rows in the same table using Hive

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

This question is a continuity of the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69506848/15012638).

I have the following table :

```
EmployeeId Dept1 Dept2 Dept3
150        10    55    6
```

this is the query to get that result :

```
SELECT  EmployeeId, Dept1, Dept2, Dept3 FROM Employee_History
```

This is my expected output :

```
EmployeeId Dept
150        10
150        55
150        6
```

Comment: `N` unions of `employeeId` and `Dept<M>` for `M` <= `N`

Comment: @astentx I can't get it

Answer (score 0):

While Hive doesn't support PIVOT and UNPIVOT querie, you can use the following :

```
select  EmployeeId
       ,pe.val    as Dept

from    Employee_History
        lateral view    posexplode(array(dept1,dept2,dept3)) pe
;
```